# Program for Sum of Factors

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program that checks for the 5th number that has 360 has the sum of its factors.

I wrote a program that gets a users entered number and prints the factors and then the sum of all those factors. The part I'm having difficulty with is having two counting variables (the number that is being checked for factors and the number that is being divided by).

Here is what I have:

```
    int number, i, total = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    printf("The factors of %i are:\n", number);

    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
            total += i;
        }

    }
    printf("The sum of all the factors of %i is %i\n", number, total);

return(0);

}
```

Comment: I don't get it. 5th number from where?

Comment: The factors of 190 are: 1, 2, 5, 10, 19, 38, 95 and 190. The sum of these factors is 360. I'm trying to find which numbers (starting from 1) have a sum of its factors which add to 360.

Comment: So, may be, instead of user input, you could put your loop into another: `for (number = 1; number <= 360; ++number) { }`. For every number >= 360, you have at least factors 1 and number (and mostly a lot more) which add to number + 1. So, for me, 360 sounds like a reasonable upper border. It's a little bit brute force but IMHO it should work.

Comment: I reread what you wanted, and the program seems correct. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Instead of inputting `number` you can use another loop that varies `number`. Btw. you can make your program much faster by observing that factors occur in pairs: when `f` is a factor of `n`, so is `n/f`. But be careful with the special case where `n` is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking a little bit about this, I came to the conclusion that 360 is a reasonable upper boundary for numbers which have to be tested.

- 360 has for sure (at least) two factors 1 and 360 (and a lot more) which add to (more than) 361.
- Any number n ≥ 360 has at least a sum of factors ≥ n + 1.

Funny, enough: 359 is a prime number and has only two factors (1, 359) which sum up to 360 (and seems to be the highest candidate).

Hence, the OP's code can be wrapped into a loop from 1 ... 360 to solve this puzzle (finding the answer with brute force).

My sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getSumFactors(int n)
{
  int sum = 1 + n;
  for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) if (n % i == 0) sum += i;
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int nF = 0;
  for (int n = 1; n <= 360; ++n) {
    if (getSumFactors(n) == 360) printf("%d.: %d\n", ++nF, n);
  }
  printf("%d numbers with factors which sum up to 360.\n", nF);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.: 120
2.: 174
3.: 184
4.: 190
5.: 267
6.: 295
7.: 319
8.: 323
9.: 359
9 numbers with factors which sum up to 360.
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5mSeoIjXjWWG9yBk)</kbd>

I'm a little bit surprised that there are only 9 candidates – had expected more. (So much about my "mathematical feeling"...)

Comment: Thank you for help! I liked seeing the numbers that added up 360.

Answer (score 1):

A configurable example with descriptive variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_EMPLOYEES (1000)

int main()
{
    int number_to_consider;
    int potential_factor;
    int factor_total = 0;
    int num_suitable_numbers_found = 0;
    int desired_factor_total = 360;
    int number_of_numbers_to_Find = 5;

    for(number_to_consider = 1; number_to_consider < 10*desired_factor_total; number_to_consider++)
    {
        factor_total = 0;
        for (potential_factor = 1; potential_factor <= number_to_consider; potential_factor++)
        {
            if ((number_to_consider % potential_factor) == 0)
            {
                factor_total += potential_factor;
            }
        }

        if (factor_total == desired_factor_total)
        {
            num_suitable_numbers_found++;
            printf("Found candidate %i : %i\n", num_suitable_numbers_found, number_to_consider);
        }

        if(num_suitable_numbers_found >= number_of_numbers_to_Find)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Found candidate 1 : 120
Found candidate 2 : 174
Found candidate 3 : 184
Found candidate 4 : 190
Found candidate 5 : 267
```

Comment: Aah. Now, I understand the part with "the 5th". Good catch.

Comment: I'm glad that I indexed my results. So, strictly speaking, the right solution can be found in my solution too. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff, Your program over delivers! ;)

Comment: Thank you for help! The way you described your variables was perfect.